# How to copy and paste rows in VBA without changing any data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to set up a macro so that when I click a button I get a window asking how many rows I want. Then it should add the rows at row 3 but I don't want it to change any data let's say one cell has a formula with B2 and the coppied row has B3 in the formula. I want the rows to stay the exact same, but I don't want to use $ sign in the row I'm trying to copy

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = InputBox("How many rows do you want to add?")
For i = 1 To n
Rows("3:3").Select
Selection.Copy
Rows("3:3").Insert
Next i
For i = 1 To n

End Sub
```

Here is the code I came up with. I'm also trying to do this in 2 worksheets at the same time with 1 button click, so if you have some insights I would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you exactly want to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @FunThomas I'm trying to write a code so that when I click a button I get a window, where I input a number. Then I want the macro to add the number of rows in 2 spreadsheets without it changing any data or formulas. For example I'm coppying a row with a formula "=Baza!D4" and it changes to "=Baza!D5" when pasting

Answer (score 0):

for first problem, try to keep .formula and re-apply it to inserted lines like this :

```
Dim f
For i = 1 To n
 Rows("3:3").Select
 f = Selection.Formula
 Selection.Copy
 Rows("3:3").Insert
Next i

For i = 1 To n
 Rows("3:3").Offset(i) = f
Next
```

others sheets can be referenced by Worksheets("SheetX") like this :

```
For i = 1 To n
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:3").Select
 f = Selection.Formula
 Selection.Copy
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:3").Insert
Next i

For i = 1 To n
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:3").Offset(i) = f
Next



For i = 1 To n
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows("3:3").Select
 f = Selection.Formula
 Selection.Copy
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows("3:3").Insert
Next i

For i = 1 To n
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows("3:3").Offset(i) = f
Next
```